# Page curl with text on Android

Tags: android, text, paging, effects

I found this amazing [harism's project](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) that allows a beautiful paging effect like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg04wfnDpiQ). But works only with bitmap images. How to do that with text? Selectable texts, copyable text, etc.

The [harism's project](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) uses GLSurfaceView.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add text but not editable one as the text will get merged with the images.

refer to this link for adding text to your harism page curl apps - [Android page curl by harism , adding TextView caused and exception :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195758/android-page-curl-by-harism-adding-textview-caused-and-exception/9883554#9883554)