# How to possible page curl with textView in android?

Tags: android, paging, android-edittext

I found the good harism's project that allows a beautiful paging effect like following link
https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl.
But works only images,My requirement is to use editText through write data and also save So,kindly give me Suggestion or code.
I also visit bellow given link:
[Android page curl by harism , adding TextView caused and exception :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195758/android-page-curl-by-harism-adding-textview-caused-and-exception/9883554#9883554)
But above link use textView not Edit Text.

Answer (score 4):

it is so simple. Just replace the loadBitmap method in the CurlActivity with the below method,

```
private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, int index) {
    Bitmap txtBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    String text1 = yourPagesStringArray[index];
    Canvas c = new Canvas(txtBitmap);
    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv.setText(text1);
    tv.setTextColor(0xa00050ff);
    tv.setTextSize(15);
    tv.setLinksClickable(true);
    tv.setLineSpacing(2, 2);
    tv.layout(0, 0, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
    tv.draw(c);

    c.drawBitmap(txtBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    return txtBitmap;
}
```

Comment: It works.. but the method name I found named `private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, int index)`.

Comment: changing the modifier is not a issue i guess

Comment: and what about webviews instead of text? is it possible?

Comment: webview is way complicated than textView. I am sorry I couldn't assist.

Comment: What if the text is too long to fill the whole rectangle,how to make it scrollable?