# How to add dynamic text-view pages to Android Page-Curl Animation

Tags: android

I  have used Harism's Page Curl animation for my application, but I have been trying to add multiple pages as like a book of 100 pages.

[Harism's Page Curl animation project](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl)

Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990855/how-to-possible-page-curl-with-textview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to add more pages, edit the line in CurlActivity.java:

```
    private int[] mBitmapIds = { R.drawable.obama, R.drawable.road_rage,
            R.drawable.taipei_101, R.drawable.world };
```

and change the page count:

```
    @Override
    public int getPageCount() {
        return 5;
    }
```

But this still requires you to use only graphics... I still have no answer for using textviews.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit...like this in Curl Activity....

```
        d.setBounds(r);
        d.draw(c);
        c.drawText("Double Tap For Zoom", 100, 60, p);//for drawing text
```